# Simple .click function not called?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

I have a table generated after an event. It contains these kind of links in `<td>`  :

```
<a class="link-capacity" href="#" id="1234">Capacity</a>
```

I want to catch the click event with JQuery on these links so I write this function :

```
$(".link-capacity").click(function () {
    console.log("OK");
});
```

This function is loaded before the table generation.

When I click on my links the function is never called. Am I missing something ? Can I create the class after the loading of my JQuery function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use [***delegate***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click",".link-capacity",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the future elements

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation using [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events to elements that are not present in DOM when event binding code is executed.

```
$(document).on("click", ".link-capacity", function () {
    console.log("OK");
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).on("click", ".link-capacity", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();// is used to prevent the default behavior of the link 
    console.log("OK");
 });
```